# Is the underlying set of every renormalization group countable and finite？

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, universal-algebra, semigroups-of-operators, renormalization

Is the underlying set of every renormalization group countable and finite？

Suppose A is a renormalization group, and the elements of it compose of the set B. Is B the set countable and finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the renormalization group of a continuum field theory contains continuously parameterized scale-changing transformations—hence an uncountable number of them.